# Cannot read property 'classList' of null but it works in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue when I'm trying to compile my react app.
The issue is "Cannot read property 'classList' of null".

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Nav extends Component {
  showMenu() {
    document.querySelector("#menu-icon").classList.toggle("is-active");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <h4>Z-LINE Meble</h4>
        <button className="hamburger hamburger--spring" id="menu-icon" type="button" onClick={this.showMenu()}>
          <span className="hamburger-box">
            <span className="hamburger-inner" />
          </span>
        </button>
        {/* <h5>Oferta</h5>
        <h5>Realizacje</h5>
        <h5>O nas</h5>
        <h5>Kontakt</h5> */}
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

What is wrong?
- While i have 'onClick' function on button, there's this error
 [image: (click me)]
- If there's no 'onClick' function it actually works by typing showMenu() content in console [image: (click me)]

Do you know how to solve that?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Is it possible showMenu is being called before render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `onClick` Listener, as the documentation said: with JSX you need to pass a function as the event handler.

But when you use:

```
onClick={this.showMenu()}
```

You are calling the function before your component is renderer, note the parenthesis at the end.

What you should do is not call it just once you click on the button.

You have two options:
1)

```
onClick={this.showMenu}
```

2) if you need to pass some parameter to the function

```
onClick={() => {this.showMenu()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Function:

```
  showMenu = () => {
        document.querySelector("#menu-icon").classList.toggle("is-active");
      }
```

and Button:

```
<button className="hamburger hamburger--spring" id="menu-icon" type="button" onClick={()=> this.showMenu()}>
```